# CONVERT_TZ('2015-08-03 21:00:00', 'GMT','Americia/Chicago') displaying one hour ahead in day light saving period

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, dst, convert-tz

I am trying to list the recurring events from google calendar. the sync successfully done  but while listing the info from my local database (saved as gmt date time) using The mysql convert_tz() I am getting the time one hour ahead while in day light saving months.

Ex:

I am saving the date with time in GMT and while displaying converting it into user's timezone
the date 2015-03-03 21:00:00 (Gmt time) is displaying as 2015-03-03 15:00:00 (in user timezone) this is fine

but for the day light saving months (after march 8) it displaying as 2015-05-03 16:00:00 (In user timezone)

I tried by updating the timezone tables but still no luck..

Comment: What's the user's timezone?

Comment: Feel free to share what was wrong.. :)

Comment: Sure,   Its a bad bug.   I said am converting to GMT time,  for the next recurring months i used the hours from the converted GMT time thats the issue.   for the recurring month i have to use the hours from start date (from the calender) then have to convert that to GMT.